# i18n Django Internationalization and database objects

Tags: django, django-models, internationalization

I'm working in a bilingual project (es/en); for this project I've chosen to use django's i18n internationalization system  (and I'm starting to regret it...)

Today's problem is the following:
for some models, my database stores information like `description` and `es_description`, or `english_common_name` and `spanish_common_name` *(these are **attributes** of my objects, and are used in many circumstances, not only for page-translation issues)*.

A sample model can be defined like:

```
def MyModel(models.Model):
    name = ...
    type = ...
    authors = ...
    contributors = ...
    ...
    ...
    description = models.TextField(max_length = 800, blank=True)
    es_description = models.TextField(max_length = 800, blank=True)
    ...
    english_common_name = models.CharField('name', max_length=80, unique=True)
    spanish_common_name = models.CharField('nombre', max_length=80, unique=True)
    ...
```

Let's say I want to retrieve this information in my template, according to `lang`, the language selected by the user.

For example, in some place of my template I could have something like

```
<h1>{{name}}</h1>
<h3>{{english_common_name}}</h3>
<p>{{description}}</p>
<p>{% trans "Contributors" %}: {{contributors}}</p>
```

How can I call `{{spanish_common_name}}` instead of `{{english_common_name}}` or `{{es_description}}` instead of `{{description}}` if the page language is set to `'es'`?

I absolutely refuse to do something like

```
<p>{% ifequal lang 'es' %}{{descrpition}}{% else %}{{es_description}}{% endifequal %}</p>
```

And if I try to manage this in views...  I don't want to define a `get_translated_content` function like this

```
def get_translated_content(en_content,es_content,lang):
    if lang is 'es':
        return es_content
    else:
        return en_content

...
# MyView
...
    return render_to_response(...,
                              {'object': my_object,
                               'object_common_name': get_translated_content(english_common_name, spanish_common_name, lang),
                               'object_description': get_translated_content(description, es_description, lang), 
                                ... ,})
```

This could work (still being an horrible solution) in simple situations, but in more complex cases I would be forced to return dictionaries which are *localized copies of the original `MyModel` object* (and if in a view I have to use lots of different instances of the same model, I would be forced to generate a biiiig list of these dictionaries).

Please, tell me that there is a good, logic way to access db object-fields according to the page's language, please!

**Edit:** after reading the answers received so far, I think I should add to my question a "*leaving the database structure (almost) unchanged*" clause.

Comment: im not sure about that, i saw django model translation but i think, its better get another DB for each language, i think its better for the performance

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You really should use something like [django-multilingual](http://code.google.com/p/django-multilingual/) (if you're using Django 1.2, see [Django 1.2 compatible branch](http://github.com/ojii/django-multilingual-ng)).

For your example (based on the [documentation](http://github.com/ojii/django-multilingual-ng/blob/master/docs/usage.rst))

```
from django.db import models
from django.utils.translation import ugettext_lazy as _
from multilingual.translation import TranslationModel

class MyModel(models.Model):
    name = ...
    type = ...
    authors = ...
    contributors = ...
    ...
    ...
    class Translation(TranslationModel):
        description = models.TextField(max_length = 800, blank=True)
        ...
        common_name = models.CharField(_(u'name'), max_length=80, unique=True)
        ...
```

Accessing translatable fields

```
my_model = MyModel.objects.get(id=1)
my_model.description # the description in the current language
my_model.common_name # the common name in the current language
my_model.name # the name
```

The current language is deteced the same way django detects it.

Comment: Wow, thank you, this solution is terrific, and it would be the perfect solution... but I would prefer not to change my models structure: the project is already working and the db is populated with a loooot of data... [Also, reading this article http://www.muhuk.com/2010/01/dynamic-translation-apps-for-django/ , looks that django-multilingual isn't the best pick at all (same for i18n) ]

Comment: Very interesting link, thanks for posting it. You can use south (http://south.aeracode.org/) to migrate your models.
Regarding django-multilingual, there's a new fork of the project that works with Django 1.2 (http://github.com/ojii/django-multilingual-ng)

Answer (score 4):

You can write a [custom template tag](http://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/howto/custom-template-tags/), that basically does

```
{% ifequal lang 'es' %}{{descrpition}}{% else %}{{es_description}}{% endifequal %}
```

but without being so ugly:

```
def get_lang(object, property, lang):
    if lang=='en':
        return object.__getattribute__(property) # TODO: deal with AttributeError
    try: # assuming other lang is 'es'
        return object.__getattribute__("es_%s" % property) # try first option of spanish property
    except AttributeError: # try other option of spanish property
        return object.__getattribute__("spanish_%s" % property) # TODO: deal with AttributeError again.
    return ""
```

Then you can call this from the template by

```
{% get_lang obj common_name lang %}
```

Answer (score 3):

> I ran into the same question and saw your post. Yet, none of the answers were good enough to my taste. *(and because this question is very old, linked libraries are outdated as well)*

## Best choice in 2019 *(IMHO)*: `django-modeltranslation`

After doing some digging and benchmarking, here is what I (personally) recommend for recent Django projects:

https://django-modeltranslation.readthedocs.io

**It fits the OP issues**: Leave the models unchanged, and handle existing I18n DB fields.

The OP case is a particular case, since the DB already contains some translation fields (which will need to be migrated, somehow), unlike my own setup which starts from scratch.

But the library addresses this issue as well, see https://django-modeltranslation.readthedocs.io/en/latest/commands.html#the-update-translation-fields-command

#### [Official features](https://django-modeltranslation.readthedocs.io/en/latest/index.html#features)

- Add translations without changing existing models or views
- Translation fields are stored in the same table (no expensive joins)
- Supports inherited models (abstract and multi-table inheritance)
- Handle more than just text fields Django admin integration Flexible
  fallbacks, auto-population and more!

---

## Libraries comparison

I quickly compared the following libraries:

- https://django-i18nfield.readthedocs.io
- https://github.com/ulule/django-linguist
- https://django-modeltranslation.readthedocs.io

I found this comparison table which helped me finding `django-modeltranslation` *(which is the most upvoted there)*:
https://djangopackages.org/grids/g/i18n/

---

## Other good resources

Note that https://github.com/WeblateOrg/weblate is also quite popular, but doesn't resolve the OP issue. Yet it looks very interesting!

Also, https://django-modeltranslation.readthedocs.io/en/latest/related_projects.html list a few other projects, but most look either similar or not mature enough.

Answer (score 2):

If it's not too late you might consider re-working your data model so that you model a one-to-many relationship between the core entities and their language-specific representations. That way your model's more normalised - you're not enshrining meta-data in your field names - and you'll find it easier to work with.

Something like:

```
class MyModel(models.Model):
    // fields that don't need translating go here
    name = ...
    type = ...

class MyModelTranslation(models.Model):
    // fields that do need translating go here
    language = models.CharField(...)
    description = models.TextField(...)
    common_name = models.TextField(...)
    parent = models.ForeignKey('MyModel', related_name="translations")

    // TODO: enforce uniqueness for any given parent/language tuple
```

Then in your view you can do something like:

```
// Get the user's chosen language, default to 'en'
lang = request.session.get('django_language', 'en')


obj = MyModel.objects.get(...)
object_text = obj.translations.filter(language__exact=lang)[0]

return render_to_response(...,
{
    'object': obj,
    'object_common_name': object_text.common_name,
    'object_description': object_text.description,
})
```

Comment: Ooh, I like Nathan's answer - hadn't come across django-multilingual before!